# How to archive files revision-safe using java?

Tags: java, hdfs, archive

I am searching for a way to archive files in a revision-save way.
I imagine a java based rest service, to pass a file, which is then unchangeable stored and accessible via an URI.
How could I implement something like this? Is a Hadoop Archive a possible building block? Or is this only possible using a Content-Addressed Storage?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to compute a checksum for each file and return the ID of the file together with the checksum as a combined access URL. Than each time a client requests a file via the URL (including the checksum), the service verifies the checksum again and can so garantie, that the file returned was not modified from the point of time when the file was stored and is identical to the version the client expect. The URL is the surety of the immutability of the requested file. 
Also the client can verify the checksum if the client did not trust the service.